# $\ f \colon X \to X $ ,continuous function where X is compact,Hausdorff space.Show $\exists A$ st $f(A) =A$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness, nets

Suppose $\ f  \colon X \to X $ is a continuous function from a compact,Hausdorff space to itself. Prove that there exists a subspace $A$ such that $f(A) =A$.

I came up with an answer based on nets (*see the answer below*). But i am not very much familiar with nets. So please point out,if there is any error in argument.

Let $Y=f(X)$ then $X= \mathop{\cup}_{y  \in Y} f^{-1}(y)$ where the union is over disjoint sets. Since each of the pullback is a closed set. Being in a normal space, $\forall \ f^{-1}(y), \  \exists \  U_{y}$ open in $X$ such that  $f^{-1}(y) \subset U_{y} \subset \overline{U_{y}} \subset X$ .

Hence $X = \bigcup_{y \in Y} U_{y} $. 
This open cover has a finite subcover. $X=U_{1} \cup U_{2} \cup \ldots \cup U_{n} $.
Let $\Sigma = \lbrace A \  \ \vert A \subset X \rbrace$, suppose $\nexists$ any $A \in \Sigma$ st $f(A) =A$ then $\forall A \in \Sigma , \ \exists \ f (x)_{A} $ st $f (x)_{A} \notin A$.

define partial order on $\Sigma$ by set inclusion so that it becomes a directed set.

Let $\ell \colon \Sigma \to X$ be a net such that $\ell(A) = f(x)_{A} $. For simplicity let us represent it the net by $(f(x)_{A})$.

Since $X$ is compact,every net has a cluster point,call the cluster point of the above net as $p$. 
Since $p \in X=U_{1} \cup \ldots \cup U_{n} $, we may assume $p \in U_{1} $.

Let $U_{1}$ be the neighbourhood of $p$ and $A=   U_{1}$ then $\exists  \ B \in \Sigma $  such that $ A \subset B $ and $f(x)_{B} \in U_{1}$. But $f(x)_{B} \notin B \Rightarrow f(x)_{B} \notin A=U_{1}$.

This is a contradiction. $\square$

Comment: i have a different answer.please go through it.

Comment: You really ought to mention it in the question if you answer your own question. Otherwise, it looks like you made no effort at all...

Comment: Often the "proof to be checked" is included in the body of the Question for these types of questions.  I'll vote to reopen, but keep it mind for future requests.

Comment: @user2902293: Your statement remains true without topology. See this link to a simple proof: http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/a-short-proof-of-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem/

Comment: @Seirios: Of course trivially $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but I suspect the goal is to prove the statement for nonempty $A$.  Here's an example to show that without topology, the trivial solution is the best one can do.  Consider $f(x) = x+1$ on $\mathbb{N}$.  Suppose $A$ were a nonempty set s.t. $f(A)=A$ and let $x$ be the least element of $A$.  Since $x \in f(A)$, there must be $y \in A$ s.t. $x= y+1$, contradicting minimality of $x$.